# In app purchases Auto renewable

Tags: ios6, in-app-purchase

your server must track purchases and allow user to restore purchased subscriptions to all iOS devices owned by a single user 
I also need to track purchases and allow user to restore purchased subscriptions to all iOS devices owned by a single user. However, I am not aware of any mechanism that will allow me to identify all iOS devices owned by a single user from the app. I am not even aware of any mechanism for identifying the AppleID used by the user from the app. So how am I supposed to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using auto-renewable subscription you can just use the restore feature of store kit. If you're using non-renewable you must allow users to share their subscription across their devices. There are several ways to accomplish this. If you own a server, you can generate a key with a purchase. Associate a number with this key that indicates how many times a user has restored to another device (say, 5). When a user then enters this key on another device, you decrease this number. You would thus have to add a "Share" button in your app that would give the user this key. And you would need an "Unlock" button where the user can enter this code. If you are interested I could also find a method for you that doesn't require a server (but this is less secure).

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

sorry, just noticed you're talking about auto renewable:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentQueue_Class/Reference/Reference.html

restoreCompletedTransactions is what you're after

Comment: i am using auto renewable if i click on subscribe i connect to the store kit and allows the user to enter apple id and after that unlocking the content is completed if the user has two devices then how can i subscribe to both the devices? i am doing this in auto renewable subscription

Comment: that's in my answer already... use "restoreCompletedTransactions". hook this method up to a "restore" button in your app so that users can click it on their second device... please click it as "answered" if it answers your question

Comment: right now when the user was opened my app he wants to login when the subscription is completed the value is stored in my database and when the user is logout and again login i am comparing with the database . here the problem is one user subscribed and then login is giving to all the persons it was working so how can i control this only the subscribed user

Comment: right now i am testing the in app purchases in simulator and what is the best way to do this in simulator or ios device

Comment: please use punctuation and rephrase your comment so i don't have to decipher what you're saying

Comment: your post solve my problem thankyou Joris Weimar and this is the only solution for inapppurchases for autorenewable process thank

Comment: can you select my answer as the right answer so the question is closed. thanks!